# Is it necessary for Apache IoTDB and HDFS to integrate to store time-series data?

Tags: hdfs, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now studying the integration of Apache IoTDB and other data softwares. I wonder if IoTDB can use HDFS as the underlying storage structure? Or is it recommended to combine these two softwares to store time-series data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cluster of Apache IoTDB already has the concept of replicas, and you can set different number of replicas using ConfigNode and DataNode. Therefore, HDFS does not need to be used as a storage replica in IoTDB.